# Pass elements of a list as arguments to a to-report function in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to pass a list as the set of arguments to a to-report function. Below is a simple example.

```
Globals 
[a
list_of_list]

to setup   
ca
set list_of_list (list (list 1 2) (list 3 4)) 
end

to go
set a function list_of_list
end

to-report function [arg1]
report (map add arg1) 
end 

to-report add [arg1 arg2]
report arg1 + arg2
end
```

However I am getting the following error.

`task expected 2 inputs, but only got 1
error while observer running MAP
  called by procedure F
  called by procedure SETUP
  called by Command Center`

The answer I'm expecting to get after passing the elements of the list as function arguments is [3 7].

The real task that I am working on is much more complicated with deeper nested lists, but this code gives the idea of what I am trying to do. Should I consider using the Matrix extension to handle nested lists more easily?

Answer (score 0):

Change your `add` function to

```
to-report add [lst]
report reduce + lst
end
```

Comment: The code I have provided is only a simplified example of the task Im working on. Therefore I am not actually using the add function. The function that I am trying to pass the elements of a list is actually much more complicated than  the `add` function here.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
map add arg1
```

with

```
map [add first ? last ?] arg1
```

If you need a more general solution, see Bryan Head’s `listify-task` procedure at https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues/539.